# Mat slider not works after migrate to Angular 14 ->15

Tags: angular, angular14, angular15, angular-migration, mat-slider

[Error slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4ivU.png)

when i am using mat slider in angular 15 i got err like[err msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jd8h.png)
my slider is not moving it is a project migrated from angular 14 to 15.
Did anyone know how to fix this?

[crt slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kbAG.png)
I want a slider like this old.

Comment: you may need to add more code snippets to understand the issue properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Angular Material 14 to 15 there have been some major changes. You can view the details here: https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration

Without seeing your code it is hard to help you in detail, but I think you will find all needed answers if you try to adapt to the following.

Firstly, you should update your Material version like this:

```
ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration
```

But nonetheless this might break some of your functionality. The parameters for mat-slider have changed. You can view the details here: https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration#slider

As a quick fix, Angular Material preserved some of the old components. You can access them by changing your imports to the legacy components:

```
import {MatLegacySliderModule } from '@angular/material/legacy-slider';
```

Nonetheless, I would recommend updating your code to the new material components. I had the same issue and at first it seemed like a lot of work to me. But in the end it is not too complicated to adjust everything and get it running again.

Stay healthy,
Tom